# Setting State not working for multiple api fetch in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, fetch-api

I am passing information (which is an array of ids) through `prop` from one `component` (component1) to another (component2).

The data can be accessed successfully in component2 but the issue is I am trying to loop through that array to get certain data from an `API`.

component1 has a link that when you click on it, it displays info from component2. When i `console.log()` the prop from component2, it displays the right info. But problematic part is fetching. When i click once, it fetches the right data but if i click again, i still get the initial data that was fetched. Below is my code

**component1**

```
…
 <div className="vehicleDetail">
    <VehicleDetail vehicles={toDisplay.vehicleID} />
 </div>
…
```

**component2**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

export default function VehicleDetail(props) {
  const [vehicleState, setVehicleState] = useState([]);
  console.log(props.vehicleID);
  useEffect(() => {
    let vehicles = [];
    props.vehicles.forEach((vehicleID, index) => {
      fetch(`/api/vehicle/${vehicleID}`)
        .then(data => {
          return data.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
          vehicles.push(data.data);
        });
    });
    setVehicleState(vehicles);
  }, []);
  return <p>Hi</p>;
}
```

I what such that when I click from component1, the data is fetched again and rendered rather than get the same initially fetched data.

Answer (score 0):

You fetch the data once on the component mount, try adding a fetching interval.

[For example](https://2wjvr.codesandbox.io/):

```js
function VehicleDetail() {
  const [vehiclesIDs, setVehiclesIDs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/')
        .then(data => {
          return data.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
          const id = data.results[0].id.value;
          setVehiclesIDs(prevState => [
            ...prevState,
            id ? id : prevState.length
          ]);
        });
    }, 3000);
    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, [setVehiclesIDs]);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Vehicles IDs Fetched every 3 sec</h1>
      <h2>
        {vehiclesIDs.map(id => (
          <div key={id}>{id}</div>
        ))}
      </h2>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Q-56818618-MultiFetch]

Comment: It console.log() infinitely

Comment: So explain in your question what are you trying to do, how you want to fetch the data? With timeout? when data changes? elaborate.

Comment: Check the updated answer, it fetches every 3 sec, use it as an example.

Comment: I passed the id as props from the first component (the id is in an array). I want to fetch data of that id in the second component everytime i click on the first component

Comment: "I want to fetch data of that id in the second component everytime i click on the first component" so make `onClick` and fetch it there?

Comment: I guess i’m the one finding it to communicate my problem but thanks for your help